# creating aws workspaces using ansible

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, amazon-workspaces

I am trying to automate the creation of aws workspaces using ansible, but I cant get the command to create the workspace right.

Here is my playbook.yml and I am running ansible on a linux ec2 instance.

```yaml
- hosts: windows
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    BundleId: "wpc-30g6060"
    DirectoryId: "d-8039964"
    UserName: "testing"

  tasks:
    - name: deploy workspaces
      command: >
        aws workspaces create-workspaces --workspaces  
        --cli-input-json '{{ lookup('template', 'workspaces.json') | to_json }}'
      delegate_to: localhost
      # loop: "{{ user_list }}"
```

Here is the workspaces.json

```json
{
      "DirectoryId": "{{ DirectoryId }}",
      "UserName": "{{ UserName }}",
      "BundleId": "{{ BundleId }}",
      "UserVolumeEncryptionEnabled": false,
      "RootVolumeEncryptionEnabled": false,
      "WorkspaceProperties": {
        "RunningMode": "ALWAYS_ON",
        "RunningModeAutoStopTimeoutInMinutes": 5,
        "RootVolumeSizeGib": 80,
        "UserVolumeSizeGib": 10,
        "ComputeTypeName": "PERFORMANCE"
      },
      "Tags": [
        {
          "Key": "",
          "Value": ""
        }
      ]
}
```

I keep getting the following error when I run the playbook

> ["", "Error parsing parameter '--cli-input-json': Invalid type: expecting map, received <class 'str'>"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}"

I cant figure out why.

Comment: Because, as would be shown in your `-v` had you used it, you are double-encoding since `{{ lookup()` will return the json, but then `| to_json` makes it look like `...json '\"{\\n\\t\\\"DirectoryId`, to say nothing of the fact you have `"{{ DirectoryId }}",` in a file you are merely asking lookup to return to you; did you perhaps mean `lookup('template'`?

Comment: i tried doing lookup('template') but I still have the same issue.                                                                            
  "msg": "non-zero return code",
    "rc": 252,
    "start": "2022-09-09 19:44:57.684069",
    "stderr": "\nError parsing parameter '--cli-input-json': Invalid type: expecting map, received <class 'str'>",
    "stderr_lines": [
        "",
        "Error parsing parameter '--cli-input-json': Invalid type: expecting map, received <class 'str'>"

Comment: Because you still have the `to_json` filter that you must drop as explained in above comment.